# mysql union does not add up all the results

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following two queries:

```
SELECT scan, mrn, ecd, babyName, badgeNumber, 'dummy' as verifiedBy, 
       adLogin, ts, 'dummy' as reason 
FROM (`Verifications`) 
LEFT JOIN `Logins` ON `Verifications`.`badgeNumber` = `Logins`.`badgeNum`
```

And

```
SELECT 'Override' as scan, mrn, ecd, babyName, badgeNumber, verifiedBy, adLogin, 
        ts, reason 
FROM (`overrides`) 
LEFT JOIN `Logins` ON `overrides`.`badgeNumber` = `Logins`.`badgeNum`
```

The first query results in 723 records and the second one results in none. but when I union the two queries the number of records is reduced to 714???

Comment: What happens if you use `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`?

Comment: well... it fixes it. But what is the difference

Comment: Read the documentation. It default to `UNION DISTINCT`, so duplicates are removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try using UNION ALL.
UNION removes the dupicate records while UNION ALL will keep the duplicates too.